# flutter:how can i received value as same as mysql database?

Tags: mysql, flutter

Hi I am try use mysql database in my flutter app...but till now fetch all data as string..what changes i have to done in my below code to received as data as my database...
in below code verify is a number and i want to received as number till time i received verify as string ....please help me ............

```
 FetchJSON() async {
    var Response = await http.get(
      "http://192.168.42.107/my_payment/getdata.php",
      headers: {"Accept": "application/json"},
    );

if (Response.statusCode == 200) {
  String responseBody = Response.body;
  var responseJSON = json.decode(responseBody);
  abc = responseJSON['username'];
  verify = responseJSON['verified'];
  setState(() {
    print('UI Updated');
  });
} else {
  print('Something went wrong. \nResponse Code : ${Response.statusCode}');
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

So essentially you want "strongly typed" data for your http response, you have to define such data yourself. Normally people do something like this:

```
class MyData {
  final String username;
  final bool verified; // assume this should be a boolean 

  MyData.fromJson(dynamic json) 
    : username = json['username'],
    verified = json['verified'] == 1; // assume you get back a number for verified
}
```

Then you can convert your `responseJSON` to `MyData` and carry on from there.